# Query regarding Zookeeper Windows API start/stop, using Zk as a windows service(using prunsrv)

Tags: windows-services, apache-zookeeper, procrun

I am using zookeeper in my product(3.3.3). 
While working with zookeeper on Windows, I am creating a service(using prunsrv) ,
I have few queries and issues. Listed them all,

Issues:
1)  zkServer.cmd didn’t start on Win server 2008 machine & Win 7 Enterprise(64 bit both), had to replace the following line,

```
java "-Dzookeeper.log.dir=%ZOO_LOG_DIR%" "-Dzookeeper.root.logger=%ZOO_LOG4J_PROP%" -cp "%CLASSPATH%" %ZOOMAIN% "%ZOOCFG%" %*
```

to

```
java "-Dzookeeper.log.dir=%ZOO_LOG_DIR%" "-Dzookeeper.root.logger=%ZOO_LOG4J_PROP%" -cp "%CLASSPATH%" %ZOOMAIN% "%ZOOCFG%"
          And it worked, could it be fixed in some other way?
```

2)  In the zoo.cnf I specified the dataDir, still it creates some other directory (bin/zookeeper-3.4.5zookeeper-3.4.5data/ version-2/snapshot) and stores the snapshots there.

Queries:
1)  There is no start/stop with zkServer.cmd as it is in zkServer.sh, so basically it is started with zkServer.cmd but to stop I do a Ctrl+C/Z
So if I start the process, it is a foreground process and gets killed when I do a ctrl+C

2)  I have to create a zookeeper service, and I am using prunsrv to do that. I figured out the following 2 ways to do so.

```
a)   

prunsrv //IS//Zookeeper --DisplayName=" ZOOKEEPER Service" --Description=" ZOOKEEPER Service" --Startup=auto --StartMode=exe --StartPath=%ZOOKEEPER_HOME% --StartImage=%ZOOKEEPER_HOME%\bin\zkServer.cmd --StopTimeout=5 --LogPath=%LOGS_DIR% --LogPrefix=zookeeper --LogLevel=Info --PidFile=zookeeper.pid --StdOutput=auto --StdError=auto


b)  

cd %ZOOKEEPER_HOME%\bin\
                call "%~dp0zkEnv.cmd"
                set ZOOMAIN=org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain
                prunsrv //IS//Zookeeper --DisplayName=" ZOOKEEPER Service" --Description=" ZOOKEEPER Service" --Jvm="%JVM_DLL%" --JvmOptions=!JAVA_OPTS!  --Environment=zookeeper.log.dir=%ZOO_LOG_DIR%;zookeeper.root.logger=%ZOO_LOG4J_PROP%; --Startup=auto --LibraryPath=%LIB_DIR% --StartMode=jvm --Classpath=%CLASSPATH% %ZOOMAIN% %ZOOCFG% --StartClass=org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain --StartMethod=start --StopMode=jvm --StopClass=org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain --StopMethod=stop --StopTimeout=10 --LogPath=%LOGS_DIR% --LogPrefix=zookeeper --LogLevel=Info --PidFile=zookeeper.pid --StdOutput=auto --StdError=auto
```

basically in the second approach I am myself doing all tasks done by the zkServer.cmd

=>> My Query is in the second step(2b), that to stop  the service there should be a stop method exposed, so that when I stop the service it is called.
So right now if I create a service and start it, ZK runs fine, but stopping it takes indefinitely, so I have to go and kill the process.
Is there some stop() for the same, I see a shutdown() but there is no description for it

I went through the class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain, here the main() is the start method( if my understanding is correct), and there should be some method to shutdown the process.

Just got the following link

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1122, exposes a start/stop, but the stop has some issues

it throws the following error:

```
E:\zookeeper-3.4.5\zookeeper-3.4.5\bin>zkServer.cmd stop
"JMX enabled by default"
"Using config: E:\zookeeper-3.4.5\zookeeper-3.4.5\bin\..\conf\zoo.cfg"
 "Stopping zookeeper ... "
ERROR: The process with PID 452 (child process of PID 4) could not be terminated.
Reason: This is critical system process. Taskkill cannot end this process.
ERROR: The process with PID 4 (child process of PID 0) could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.
ERROR: The process with PID 0 (child process of PID 0) could not be terminated.
Reason: This is critical system process. Taskkill cannot end this process.
STOPED
```

I am running this stop command on a Administrator console.

E:\zookeeper-3.4.5\zookeeper-3.4.5\bin>tasklist | findstr "java"
java.exe                     10324 Console                    1     36,036 K.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 4):

So what you want to do is run Zookeeper as a Windows service. I had the same requirement, here is the solution I have chosen:

1. Prereqs: Zookeeper & [prunsrv](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html)
2. Set `ZOOKEEPER_SERVICE` environment variable to the name of the windows service to create, and `ZOOKEEPER_HOME` to the path to the zookeeper home folder. Then,

   ```
   prunsrv.exe "//IS//%ZOOKEEPER_SERVICE%" ^
           --DisplayName="Zookeeper (%ZOOKEEPER_SERVICE%)" ^
           --Description="Zookeeper (%ZOOKEEPER_SERVICE%)" ^
           --Startup=auto --StartMode=exe ^
           --StartPath=%ZOOKEEPER_HOME% ^
           --StartImage=%ZOOKEEPER_HOME%\bin\zkServer.cmd ^
           --StopPath=%ZOOKEEPER_HOME%\ ^
           --StopImage=%ZOOKEEPER_HOME%\bin\zkServerStop.cmd ^
           --StopMode=exe --StopTimeout=5 ^
           --LogPath=%ZOOKEEPER_HOME% --LogPrefix=zookeeper-wrapper ^
           --PidFile=zookeeper.pid --LogLevel=Info --StdOutput=auto --StdError=auto
   ```
3. Add a zkServerStop.cmd file in zookeeper bin folder with the following content:

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal
   TASKLIST /svc | findstr /c:"%ZOOKEEPER_SERVICE%" > %ZOOKEEPER_HOME%\zookeeper_svc.pid
   FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%G IN (%ZOOKEEPER_HOME%\zookeeper_svc.pid) DO (
       @set zkPID=%%G
   )
   taskkill /PID %zkPID% /T /F
   del %ZOOKEEPER_HOME%/zookeeper_svc.pid
   endlocal
   ```

   (Of course it needs the two environment variables `ZOOKEEPER_HOME` & `ZOOKEEPER_SERVICE` to be set)

Hope it helps,
Guillaume.